# Featured Images in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-featured-image

Good afternoon all,

I have recently installed a new theme on my Wordpress blog to get with the times as this new theme works really well on mobile whereas my current theme doesn't.

What I like about this new theme is that uses thumbnails for the blog posts by linking to the "Featured Image" inside the blog post admin panel.

This is great, however, all of my 10,000+ articles do not have a Featured Image assigned to them as my previous theme did not use it.

I have an image that I link to at the top of my articles, which is what I use for the thumbnails when the article is shared to social media etc. These images are uploaded to a different part of my website and I link to them, so they are not stored in the Wordpress Media Library.

My question now is: Is there a way that I can make it so my Wordpress blog automatically uses the "first image in content" for the "Featured Image"?

I don't think there are any plugins to do this, so I believe it is some code that I may need to change in the backend of my blog?

I look forward to a response.

Thank you.

Comment: Can it be safely assumed that the first image attached to the post is also the first image displayed in content?

Comment: Hi @Caleb - I have always uploaded images to a different part of my website via the server and then link to those at the top of my article. I was hoping there would be some sort of code I can try that will automatically get the "first image in content" as the "featured image"? I must point out that even though the images are stored on my domain's server, they are not uploaded to the Media section of Wordpress.

Comment: The images are not in the WordPress Media Library?

Comment: Sorry @Caleb - I just edited my comment above. No they are not stored in the WordPress Media Library.

Comment: Okay. Will you please edit the question to include that info?

Comment: Yes of course, done :)

Answer (score 0):

This plugin looks like it may suit your need well: https://wordpress.org/plugins/quick-featured-images/.

> It sets, replaces and removes featured images for hundreds of posts and pages in one go. You can run it over all contents or let it work only to desired contents by using flexible filters.

Comment: This question is now invalid after OP provided additional context. However, going to leave it here for others that might end up here later. Please don't downvote.

Answer (score 0):

The images not being in the Media Library might actually make this easier: a combination of a regular expression to identify the URL of the first image in the post, plus [`download_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/download_url/), [`wp_handle_sideload()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_handle_sideload/), and [`wp_insert_attachment()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_attachment/) will complete this.

You could bypass the use of `download_url()` by providing the current image path to `wp_handle_sideload()`; that's up to you.

The regular expression would look something like this:

```php
preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
```

Source: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/60267/59678

Similar question's answer with example:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/251512/59678

Comment: Thank you for your help Caleb. I'm sorry but could you explain a little bit more please regarding this answer (I'm just trying to fully understand it). If I place this code in my Functions.php file, will it automatically make the "Featured Image" on a blog post to show the "First Image In Content" link? Or does it automatically upload the "First Image In Content" to my Media Library in Wordpress? Thank you so much for your answer by the way.

Comment: It will upload the first image in each post into the Media Library, and then set it as the post's featured image.

Comment: Thanks Caleb :D How exactly does this code work? Do I just place it at the bottom of my functions.php file? Or do I need to replace one of the below codes with it? Do I then just refresh my website or is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: ```preg_match_all(
  "#([\"']?)("
   . '(?:([\w-]+:)?//?)'
   . '[^\s()<>]+'
   . '[.]'
   . '(?:'
    . '\([\w\d]+\)|'
    . '(?:'
     . "[^`!()\[\]{}:'\".,<>«»“”‘’\s]|"
     . '(?:[:]\d+)?/?'
    . ')+'
   . ')'
  . ")\\1#",
  $content,
  $post_links
 );```

Comment: ```preg_match_all( $regexp, str_replace( "'", '', $input_string ), $matches );```